# Is there any algorithm/method to detect rumors on social media like Twitter?

Tags: python, twitter, lda

I want to detect potential rumors spreading in twitter on a specific topic like "Mexico earthquake". I used topic modelling approach like LDA(in python). I trained my LDA on the tweets which I crawled and then tested the same lda model on the newspaper articles and then found the document similarity between a newspaper article and each of the tweets which I crawled. But,the results are not satisfying. I am still unable to tell which tweet has the potential to be a rumor.

How else can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make it clear that by lda you mean Latent Dirichlet allocation and not Linear Discriminant Analysis.

But from what I understand of your question, topic modelling doesn't seem to be the way to go. First of all recall that your tweets have a very small amount of text(roughly 280 characters) so it will be tough to extract rumors from the data.

The only thing I can think of is (given that you have the tweets regarding the same topic) to run a clustering algorithm such as knn to partition similar topics. You can then assume that data in the same cluster is similar to one another.

Something like this maybe: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8054520/